# Error when start the r-node

Tags: r

I got this error when I started the r-node server:

```
./run-server.sh 

node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: libR.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at Object..node (module.js:416:11)
    at Module.load (module.js:336:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:297:12)
    at require (module.js:348:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/software/r-node-v0.1.1/server/rserve.js:21:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:404:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:410:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:336:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:297:12)
    at require (module.js:348:19)
```

I installed the nodejs and just followed the steps. I also searched for libR.so， which located in /usr/lib/R/lib and I add this to the system path, but r-node server still could not find it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `/usr/lib/R/lib/` is known to the program running this.

When you run R itself, it adds this to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the script `/usr/bin/R`.  You need to do this too, and possible ways to set it are

- via a one-line file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`
- via `/etc/ld.so.conf`
- via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Thank you! I got a new error: Error: Cannot find module '../lib/multipart/multipart'

Comment: I don't know anything about multipart, sorry.

Comment: That was messed up by the r-node's symbolic links.